# Should you rehydrate dry yeast?

Tags: yeast, fermentation, techniques, dry-yeast

I've read conflicting opinions on whether or not to re-hydrate dried yeast.  I've had successful fermentation with dried yeast in the past but have not tried re-hydrating.  Has anyone had better/worse experience with one way over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would always recommend creating a yeast starter - with dry or wet yeast.  A small 500 - 1500 ml starter helps the yeast get off to a great start in the new brew.

To make a starter - pour 1 L water in a small pan, add 1/4 pound dried malt extract, a teaspoon of yeast nutrient and about half a hop pellet.  Boil this for 10 minutes - then cool to about 70 degree Fahrenheit.  Pitch your yeast in this and wait 1 day before using it for your new batch of beer.

This will help any yeast, wet or dry, but especially dry, as there are typically not enough cells in the dry package for a proper pitching rate.  It also tends to produce a cleaner, better fermenting beer that floccuates more fully.

Comment: Why is this process better than pitching the dry yeast right into the fermenter?

Comment: @spoulson: Yeast starters can [expedite the fermentation process as well as help avoid certain pitfalls](http://www.beersmith.com/blog/2008/04/01/making-a-yeast-starter-for-your-home-brew-beer/).

Comment: Even with a starter, you should re-hydrate the yeast first. Introducing sugar first can affect the cell wall membranes (http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter6-5.html). I re-hydrate first, then make a starter with the rehydrated yeast.

Comment: So why 1L and 1/4 lb DME?  Why those quantities?  Should that vary based on batch size? Should it vary based on OG?  Target ABV?

Answer (score 3):

I would always recommend re hydrating the yeast. For some beers, especially in the 1040-1060 range you probably don't need to make a starter, as the yeast packet actually contains enough yeast for a beer that size.

Instead of guessing, use a Yeast Pitching Calculator, like [Jamil Zainasheff's here](http://www.mrmalty.com/calc/calc.html). Too much yeast can be a problem, too.

Answer (score 1):

My the owner of my LHBS told me to sprinkle the dried yeast on top of the chilled wort, and destroy the instructions that came with the yeast.

Comment: I've heard that too.  Safale seems to recommend doing it as well.

Comment: Its a nice idea but only works if the packet of yeast is actually viable. Pitching dead yeast does nothing useful. if the yeast is fresh/viable then pitching directly is useful and generally produces the desired results. If the yeast is not fresh/viable then pitching it gives a false sense of security which is only shattered the next day when no activity is seen in the fermentation vessel. By then it is quite possible that the "not so friendly bacteria" have arrives to lend a hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can make great beer without rehydrating dry yeast, because as you are pitching trillions of yeast cells, you can stand to kill a lot of them.  If you rehydrate in wort, the osmotic pressure on the yeasts is not ideal.  They really just want water and a higher gravity rehydration can kill the majority of the dry yeast.

Ideally, for the fastest start, it is recommended that you rehydrate the yeast in 90-100F water, then allow it to slowly cool down to the temperature of the wort into which you are pitching.  One way to do this is to rehydrate for 15 minutes, then double the volume of the rehydrating yeast with some of your wort.  I have had batches with a kraeusen in under 8 hours with rehydrated yeast.

We all know that getting a fast start helps your pitched yeast outcompete unwanted yeasts, bacteria, etc.  Also, the more active yeast you pitch, the shorter and more complete your fermentation.

Comment: I think trillions is a bit of an overstatement. I thought that a sachet of dry yeast contained something like 200 billion cells. The wyeast smack packs claim to have 100 billion. I would also bet to say the way to get the fastest start is to have a yeast starter already fermenting away. I've had my airlock going crazy within as little as an hour with a nice layer of krausen at the top of the carboy.